# How to load CNN Trained model using Caffe framework in openCV for testing(predicting/classification) new image?

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

After training lenet model in caffe framework using 10k images,i got the model lenet_iter_4000.caffemodel which contains weights and baises. I did in caffe for predicting test image classification, Now i wanted to do classification in OpenCV by loading this caffemodel for test image, Can anybody please help me how to combine caffe and OpenCV for predicting new image..

Comment: Refer to classify.py in caffe-master/python to get started

Comment: Hi...@AnoopK.Prabhu I already did classification in caffe framework,I wanted to do it in opencv by loading trained caffe model into opencv and giving new test image in mat format as input to trained model in opencv and want to classify new test image in opencv itself.I wanted to integrate caffe with opencv..

Comment: The problem that you have is pretty straight forward. Try to do the stuff, in case you get stuck somewhere, you can seek help in SO. You can make use of memory data layer for sending images as input to caffe library.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV [contrib](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules) contains a module called [dnn](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/d0f/group__dnn.html#gsc.tab=0) that can be used for this, it can load Caffe and Torch models, and [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/de7/tutorial_dnn_googlenet.html#gsc.tab=0) is a tutorial for GoogleNet, you can easily adapt it to use another network, the code is basically the same.

An alternative is the [classification.cpp](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp) example in Cafee's source, which uses OpenCV to read an image and process it with Caffe.

Comment: Hi @Matias Valdenegro could you give some idea about performance of using dnn. when i try [this](http://demo.caffe.berkeleyvision.org/classify_url?imageurl=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.opencv.org%2F3.1.0%2Fspace_shuttle.jpg)  i see "CNN took 0.059 seconds.". do you have any idea of process time on an avarage computer

Comment: @sturkmen I am not sure what you mean, DNNs are complex models so they are pretty slow, but evaluating on GPUs is pretty fast.